# Symfony: queryBuilder without mapped field

Tags: symfony, class, doctrine, entity, query-builder

it's possible to create a QueryBuilder in Symfony with fields that not appear in the Entity Class.

Something like this:

MyEntity Class:
 id, name, color

DB Table: id, name, color, **number**

And then, I'm triying to do this:

```
    $filterBuilder = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
        ->getRepository('XXXXBundle:MiEntity')
        ->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->select('o.number')
        ->..........
    ;
```

But I get this error:

Error: Class XXXXX has no field or association named **number**

Comment: can you please show your entity?

Comment: My entity has not "number" (and i have to no put "number" in the class, but exists in DB table.

Comment: you need to add number into your entity I think because doctrine is mapped by Its entity

Comment: Are there another way to not include "number" in the Entity Class? is a "personal field for a client" in a multitenant SaaS.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you should still add an unmapped "number" proporty to your class, but if you insist, you can use a native query to fetch whatever you want from the DB.

> Here is an example that selects all users with an age > 20 :
>
> $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM MyProject\Model\User u
>   WHERE u.age > 20');
>   $users = $query->getResult();

As seen on [Doctrine Query Language documentation page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)